# Python Dash Cytoscape adjust size of text to fit (inside) nodes

Tags: python, text, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I am attempting to fit the text that applies to specific nodes in a network however i cannot adjust the code that i have wrote in order too fit the text to the nodes without loosing bits of the text, the code i have wrote is as follows the difficulty that i have with it is that the node and the text are technically separate so any relative sizing is irrelevant and the text sizing does not respond correctly.

```
'selector': '[id = "twenty-six"]',
              'style': {
                        'label': objects[26],
                        'shape': 'rectangle',
                        'width': '70px',
                        'height': '100px'
                        }
```

Comment: Could you provide  a Minimal Reproducible Example

Comment: Not really, The pairing is as follows                    
        {'data': {'id': 'twenty-six'}, 
        'position': {'x': 335, 'y': 200},
        'locked': True,
        'classes': 'node_26'
        },